# Deinterlacing in ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-processing

I've followed the tutorial [here](http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/) to load video files into a C program. But the frames aren't deinterlaced.

From what I've seen, the ffmpeg executable supports a -deinterlace switch. How to I do this in code? What library/functions should I read about?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to manually call `avpicture_deinterlace` to deinterlace each decoded frame.    The function definition can be found [here](http://cekirdek.uludag.org.tr/~ismail/ffmpeg-docs/imgconvert_8c.html#1063bc5655ac0ffa549604cd6306759b).  It will basically look like this (using the variables from the first page of the tutorial):

```
avcodec_decode_video(pCodecCtx, pFrame, &frameFinished,
                     packet.data, packet.size);

if(frameFinished) {
    avpicture_deinterlace((AVPicture*)pDiFrame, 
                          (const AVPicture*)pFrame, 
                          pCodecCtx->pix_fmt, 
                          width, 
                          height);
     . 
     . 
     .
 }
```

Keep in mind that you have to initialize `pDiFrame` similarly to how they initialize `pFrameRGB` in the tutorial by creating your own buffer and calling `avcodec_alloc_frame` and `avpicture_fill`, only this time the pixel format will be that of the decoded frame(`pCodecCtx->pix_fmt`), not 24-bit RGB.

After deinterlacing, you can then perform the conversion from the deinterlaced frame to RGB as it shows in the tutorial.