# Deinterlacing in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg

I have a video stream stored in an MPEG file. Interlacing is strongly visible where there is motion and I need to de-interlace.

When doing it by software (averaging every other line), the result is not satisfactory, strong artifacts remain at places.

So I was wondering if it was possible to enforce deinterlacing somewhere in the decoding chain (which is ffmpeg), or even decode the odd/even fields separately. I am using the VideoCapture capture object, which doesn't seem to provide any level of control.

It could also be that the stream was MPEG'd without caring for interlacing, but I have no means to check that. To make things a little worse, OpenCV does not even return the FourCC of the stream.

Comment: There are some pretty smart folks on SO who know `ffmpeg`, maybe if you added that tag, someone might know how to re-encode in half frames so that your stream is processable via VideoCapture. Just a thought.

Comment: @MarkSetchell: good suggestions, thanks.

Comment: Could be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165517/deinterlacing-in-ffmpeg